# Compare key object with string value in javascript and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a variable named datesPrintable with key objec represent months and array values days from that month:

```
{12:[18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]}
```

In angular template I have two nested ng-repeat directives and i run over this like this:

```
ng-repeat="(month,days) in datesPrintable"
    ng-repeat="day in days track by $index"
```

Inside it, i call a method passing this variables:

```
isDayAvailable(day, month);
```

Inside this function, i´m comparing month with another variable (call it myMonth) to check if are equals, while in chrome works in ie that doesnt work because month is a key object (I think):

In the console I print this:

```
var myMonth = '12';

console.log(myMonth); // 12
console.log(month); // 12
console.log(typeof myMonth); // string
console.log(typeof month); // string
console.log(month.length); // 2 in chrome; 3 in ie
console.log(month == myMonth); // true in chrome; false in ie;
```

Can anyone help me comparing this? I cant change the structure because its used in many places.

Comment: Maybe [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)?

Comment: @barbsan Nop, If i do it, in ie throws NaN in month variable and undefined for month.length

Comment: That `month.length` thing is obvious, because `parseInt` returns number, not a string, you'll have to convert both variables to numbers and compare their values. What's that third character in IE?

Answer (score 1):

If in IE your `month` returns `NaN` when you try converting it to int, it propably doesn't start with space. 
You can try extract number part using regex that matches 1 or 2 digits (remove `1,` if you use only 2-digit month format with leading 0):

```
/\d{1,2}/
```

```js
var month = "{12";

console.log("This should be 12: ", parseInt(" 12"))
console.log("This should be NaN: ", parseInt(month))

var regex = /\d{1,2}/;

var result = month.match(regex);
if (result){
  month = result[0];
  console.log(month)
  // now compare with myMonth
}
```

PS. Note that creating regex in each function call could be not efficient. Better create it once and reuse

Comment: This works perfectly, my doubt now is... how can i see which is the first character of the "month" variable? And... Why in chrome it has a length of 2 and 3 in ie?...

Comment: Check `console.log(month.charAt(0))` it may be worth also look at `month.charCodeAt(0)`

Comment: Its seems a white space but, why it has a white space in ie and not in chrome? :/

Comment: What does `charCodeAt` return?

Comment: 49 in chrome and 8206 in ie

Comment: Char with 8206 code is [left-to-right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) mark. Apparently chrome is smart enough to trim it, but IE isn't. Doesn't `month.trim()` remove that character?

Comment: It due to i´m getting this value from a date with  `var langMonth = start.toLocaleString(language, defaultOptions);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177328/discussion-between-barbsan-and-manguiti).

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have the month number as a value, not a key. In javascript, you should compare with `===`, instead of `==`. Try to `month.trim()` your vars, or parse them to a number: `parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the triple equals to compare them. It compares both value and type, whilst '==' try to convert your variables to the same type to compare only the value.

```
12 == '12' //true
12 === '12' //false
```